# How can I debug a Ruby method and see the value of my local variables changing?

Tags: ruby, debugging

Take for example the following method, and then the calling of the method:

```
def count(n)
  x=3
  y=5

  n+=x
  n-=y

  puts n
end

count(3)
```

I was wondering if there is anyway that when I go to run this script in my terminal, when it gets to the count(3) line where the method is actually being called, rather than simply output "n", is there anyway I can step through the method line by line with a window where I can see my local variables (n, x and y) so that I can see the value of "n" changing as the method executes before that final value is outputted to my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with the [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) gem.

You can either add breakpoints anywhere in your code by simply inserting a `byebug` line, or you can run the entire script in debug mode by invoking your script like so:

```
byebug something-awesome.rb
```

When you enter debug mode, you can step through your code one line at a time using the `step` command.

Here's an example of what this process would look like:

```
[1, 10] in /Desktop/something-awesome.rb
=>  1: def count(n)
    2:   x = 3
    3:   y = 5
    4:
    5:   n += x
    6:   n -= y
    7:
    8:   puts n
    9: end
   10:
(byebug) step

[2, 11] in /Desktop/something-awesome.rb
    2:   x = 3
    3:   y = 5
    4:
    5:   n += x
    6:   n -= y
    7:
    8:   puts n
    9: end
   10:
=> 11: count(3)
(byebug) step

[1, 10] in /Desktop/something-awesome.rb
    1: def count(n)
=>  2:   x = 3
    3:   y = 5
    4:
    5:   n += x
    6:   n -= y
    7:
    8:   puts n
    9: end
   10:
(byebug) step

[1, 10] in /Desktop/something-awesome.rb
    1: def count(n)
    2:   x = 3
=>  3:   y = 5
    4:
    5:   n += x
    6:   n -= y
    7:
    8:   puts n
    9: end
   10:
(byebug) x
3
```

Notice that after I've stepped past line 2 (at the bottom of the console output), I can now type `x` to see what the value of `x` is at this point in the code.

For a list of all available commands, check out the [commands section](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug#byebugs-commands) of the Byebug docs.

Comment: How would you use the gem for the example given by the OP?

Comment: That's an excellent update which gives any reader a taster of what the gem can do. Nice (Winter Bash) hairstyle too, suits you:)

Comment: @SagarPandya It's a source of extra warmth for the quickly approaching winter. :-D

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely love the [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) gem.

It's an awesome and powerful interface that allows you to change directory through instances and classes (i.e. `cd User.first`), list methods (`ls`) and even interact with the shell (`shell-mode; .pwd`) - all by dropping a simple `binding.pry` from wherever you want it to kick in.

Also worth noting that Ruby 2.5 is coming with `binding.irb` shipping - I've not taken a look at it yet, but that'll be the native equivalent and hopefully remove the need for third party gems.